# Counting the number of rows in a table NOT using jquery

Tags: javascript

```
<head>
<script language="javascript">
// must have the onload handler
onload = function countRows(){
    var rows = document.getElementById('myTableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows.length;
    alert( rows);
// outputs 3
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="myTableId">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td></td><td><input onclick="doA_Function_That_Includes_CountRows()" />
            </td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to count the number of rows in the table, or tbody?

Comment: In the tbody.  the table has a header and other rows outside the tbody I don't want to count.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rows = document.getElementById('myTableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8URn/

It will count the number of `<tr>`s in the `<tbody>`, which in turn will be the number of rows in the table.

Do note that it will NOT count all of the rows in the **table** only in the **table body**. If you have a `<thead>` or a `<tfoot>` or even a row outside of the tbody, it will not be counted.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work unless the function is initiated after the TBODY in the HTML.  I can't put a call to the function in the header.  I have to put it after the Tbody.

Comment: Obviously. as with any JavaScript code, if an element is not yet downloaded by the browser, it doesn't exist on the page. As a general good practice, `<script>` tags (which have DOM implications) should come at the very bottom of the `<body>` element.

Comment: @phpmeh Sure you do! It can not count an element, which wat not yet created.

Comment: @MichaelSazonov who were to talking to here? :P

Comment: @MichaelSazonov in which case notify him using the @ sign, like I'm notifying you. (Otherwise he doesn't get notified and probably doesn't know you messaged him)

Comment: @phpmeh, Truth, FutureReaders: When you do `getElementsByTagName`, you're doing a DOM selection in order to create a new collection of elements. Because tables and tbodies maintain their own collections of rows, it is better to use that instead of making the browser do the work of amassing an identical collection. You can reference that collection via the `.rows` property.

Answer (score 12):

Another way, using the [`rows` property *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows):

```
var num = document.getElementById('myTableId').rows.length;
```

If you only want to count the rows from the first `tbody` element, select it first ([`tBody` property *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.tBodies))

```
var num = document.getElementById('myTableId').tBodies[0].rows.length;
```

Comment: I got it to work this way.  It was giving me 1.  When I put the call to the function after my tbody, it works.  Unfortunately, I need to call the function at the beginning of the Tbody.

Comment: @phpmeh: You can only reference or get information about a DOM element after it was created.

Comment: @phpmeh: You can't see rows that don't exist. That said, the `.rows` collection is live, and will update when rows are added/removed from the table.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working implementation:

```
var table = document.getElementById("myTableId");
var tbody = table.tBodies[0];
alert(tbody.rows.length);
```

And a sample jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9a6zK/

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var numberOfRows = document.getElementById('myTableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
```

Comment: I had tried.  It was returning 1 as well.  It seems to be it matters where the function is called.

Comment: @phpmeh: Oh, it wasn't in an `onload` handler? Okay... put it in an `onload` handler :)