# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined while accessing arraylist through Json Object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, struts2

I am returning an array list from my struts2 action class. 
When I an trying to access that Array list in my JavaScript file through JSON,

I am getting

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

in below line `json.EmpListByOffsetAndLength`

See my code below. I want to display data that is in `arraylist` into the table in my jsp page.

```
alert(url);
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    cache : false,
    url : url,
    success : function(json) {
        var table = document.getElementById("tablereload");
        var rowCount = document.getElementById("tablereload").rows.length;

        alert("this is row count" +rowCount);

        $("#test").html('');

        $.each(json.EmpListByOffsetAndLength, function(index, value) {
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var i = 0;

            for ( var key in value) {
                var val = value[key];

                alert(val);
                var cell = row.insertCell(i);

                var div = document.createElement('div'), // create
                // DIV
                // element
                txt = document.createTextNode(val); // create
                // text
                // node
                div.appendChild(txt);
                cell.appendChild(div);

                i++;
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: What does `console.log(json.EmpListByOffsetAndLength);` show? You need to debug and see what the issue is.

Comment: My first guess would be `json` doesn't have an `EmpListByOffsetAndLength` property, possibly due to not being parsed as JSON by jQuery because you haven't declared a `dataType` in your AJAX request.

Answer (score 4):

I think you didn't mention the dataType in ajax ...

```
 $.ajax({
          url:"",
          type:"post",
          dataType:"json",
           success:function(outputdata){ //do somethins
               console.log(outputdata);   
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if your selector is working properly? I suspect this line does not return a valid object:

```
var table = document.getElementById("tablereload");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this? You'll need to make sure you use the tbody tag in your table.

```
var rowCount = document.getElementById('tablereload').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
```

Found here: [Counting the number of rows in a table NOT using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369467/counting-the-number-of-rows-in-a-table-not-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.

Issue is resolved. I actually , my arraylist in Java is EmpListByOffsetAndLength , but in console it is coming up as json object with e mpListByOffsetAndLength i.e. with small 'e' . thats why, when we are running length function over it, it was displaying cnnot read length function for underfined object.